# Как получить ответ от приложения в командной строке cmd?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Например пишем `C:\app.exe /h` жмем **Enter** и получаем ответ "Команда выполнена".

Windows Form - C# (файл Program.cs)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: Нет :) оно не хочет передавать командной строке **cmd** текст, видимо нужно как-то обозначить отправку текста в **cmd**, вот и не знаю как...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть несколько вариантов:

- создать новую консоль:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using WindowsFormsApp2;

  static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      AllocConsole();
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");

      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());

    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();
  }
  ```
- приаттачится к консоли:

  ```
  public class GUIConsoleWriter
  {
    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    StreamWriter _stdOutWriter;

    public GUIConsoleWriter()
    {
      var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
      _stdOutWriter = new StreamWriter(stdout);
      _stdOutWriter.AutoFlush = true;

      AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
  }
  ```

Program.cs:

```
    static class Program
    {
      [STAThread]
      private static void Main()
      {
        var consoleWriter = new GUIConsoleWriter();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello");

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
      }
    }
```

То есть если Вы запускаете свое приложение с уже запущенной консоли, или с Far Manager то что бы получить результат в их окно вывода - используйте второй вариант. Первый если консоль нужно создать.

**Источник:** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)

P.S: не забудьте поблагодарить авторов оригинальных ответов =)

Comment: Спасибо :) вроде приаттачился, теперь после команды /h появляется текст "Hello" код выложу, посмотрите нет ли в нем ошибок.

Comment: @Vitokhv, ну так правильно, потому что если вы скопировали мой пример, то в нем есть строчка `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` которая и выводи `Hello` в консоль, если Вам нужно что то свое выводит, поменяйте её текст. Это я использовал для теста.

Comment: @Anton_Komyshan просто мне вообще ничего не выводило никакого текста :) отправил код ниже, посмотрите, авторов поблагодарил :)

Answer (score 2):

В .NET для запуска нового процесса используется статический метод [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает экземпляр класса [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx). У этого класса есть свойство, которое предоставляет доступ к потоку, в который программа может выводить сообщения: [StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx). Доступ дается не напрямую, а через [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx), что даже удобнее. Для того, чтобы программа выводила результат не в консоль, а в StandardOutput, необходимо в свойствах процесса ([ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)), включить опцию [RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx).

Если перед вами стоит задача запустить консольное приложение из своей программы и прочитать то, что оно выведет в консоль, воспользуйтесь методом Process.Start для запуска приложения, и используйте StreamReader полученный из StandardOutput, чтобы прочесть результат. Например, можно прочитать все данные которые содержит поток в текстовом формате используя метод [ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx).

Но есть нюанс. Нельзя сразу взять и прочитать ответ, потому что процессу требуется некоторое время чтобы выполнить работу и вывести результат в консоль. Метод ReadToEnd будет ожидать завершения процесса. Если во время ожидания необходимо чтобы ваша программа продолжала функционировать (например перерисовывать окно, реагировать на действия пользователя), используйте метод [ReadToEndAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync(v=vs.110).aspx), который вызовет делегат по завершению и передаст ему результат, или метод [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает управление по мере получения строк, а не дожидается окончания процесса.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\app.exe", @"/h");
// можно даже скрыть окно запущенного процесса
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
// указываем что программа должна выводить резульат в поток привязанный к свойству StandardOutput
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// запускаем процесс
Process procCommand = Process.Start(startInfo);
// получаем ответ запущенного процесса
StreamReader srIncoming = procCommand.StandardOutput;
string result = srIncoming.ReadToEnd();
```

Пример взят и переработан из этой статьи: [Запуск командной строки и получение ответа](http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=962&mode=show).

Comment: Спасибо, что расписали все методы, обязательно почитаю, так как новичок в этом деле :)

Answer (score 0):

Код получился такой (надеюсь ошибок в нем нет):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var consoleWriter = new GUIConsoleWriter();
        var form = new Form1();
        bool needRun = true;

        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            switch (arg)
            {
                case "/h":
                    Console.WriteLine("Команда выполнена");
                    form.Check1();
                    needRun = false;
                    break;

                case "/s":
                    Console.WriteLine("Команда выполнена");
                    form.Check2();
                    needRun = false;
                    break;

                case "/e":
                    Console.WriteLine("Команда выполнена");
                    form.Check3();
                    needRun = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (needRun)
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }

    public class GUIConsoleWriter
    {
        private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

        StreamWriter _stdOutWriter;

        public GUIConsoleWriter()
        {
            var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
            _stdOutWriter = new StreamWriter(stdout);
            _stdOutWriter.AutoFlush = true;

            AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще один более простой способ:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var form = new Form1();
        if (AttachConsole(-1))
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                switch (arg)
                {
                    case "/h":
                        form.Check1();
                        Console.Write("\r\n" + "Команда /h выполнена");
                        break;

                    case "/s":
                        form.Check2();
                        Console.Write("\r\n" + "Команда /s выполнена");
                        break;

                    case "/e":
                        form.Check3();
                        Console.Write("\r\n" + "Команда /e выполнена");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int procid);
```

Источник: [ссылка](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3273ff67-2f97-4df5-b5df-2216690a5d8c/)